# Return a ping test result in Python

Tags: python, networking, tcp, latency

I'm trying to print results from a ping test on Windows. However, when the website times out the following error occurs:

IndexError: list index out of range.

Obviously, it's looking for the results but how can I make it say "Website not available" when it does time out?

```
try:
    ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "5", website], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = ping.communicate()

    minimum = int(re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)[0])
    maximum = int(re.findall(r"Maximum = (\d+)", out)[0])
    average = int(re.findall(r"Average = (\d+)", out)[0])
    packet = int(re.findall(r"Lost = (\d+)", out)[0])

    if packet > 1:
        packet = 5 / packet * 100

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print "Couldn't get a ping"
```

Comment: have you checked if error: ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like

**edit** : try this:

```
import re
import subprocess
website = "google.com"
try:
    ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "-c 5", website], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = ping.communicate()
    if out:
        try:
            minimum = int(re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)[0])
            maximum = int(re.findall(r"Maximum = (\d+)", out)[0])
            average = int(re.findall(r"Average = (\d+)", out)[0])
            packet = int(re.findall(r"Lost = (\d+)", out)[0])
            if packet > 1:
                packet = 5 / packet * 100
        except:
            print "no data for one of minimum,maximum,average,packet"
    else:
        print 'No ping'

except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print "Couldn't get a ping"
```

Comment: That's weird, I ran my code and it worked okay.  Can you post the rest of yours?  ps: beware that in your snippet your `except` is indented too far.

Comment: It works when the website is pingable, otherwise downed websites produces this error: minimum = int(re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: okay, I updated my answer, I realized the problem was you were trying to obtain `re` results when there were none.

Comment: no problem!  It would probably be a good idea to set up your regexes as functions that raise informative erros so that when you get to `except:` you can properly tell the user what went wrong.